# JavaFX constantly updating GUI without button

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, javafx

I am making an Oscilloscope using JavaFX for making the GUI. The task is to read the values from USB (between 0 and 1023) and show it graphically. I have built the GUI from what I have learnt from tutorials. My problem is how can I constantly and simultaneously update the GUI and also keep reading data from the usb?

Many other questions like this have been answered on Stackoverflow, but the answers provide a button which causes changes. Which is not in my case.

Comment: If you use one of the build-in chart classes for displaying the values, you will be able to only add the new values to the backing observable list. All updating and refreshing, also animation will be done by the classes.

Answer (score 1):

This should be fairly simple. If your API for reading the values from USB is synchronous you have to place the relevant call in a separate thread. If the API is asynchronous (uses some kind of callback to notify you about new values) then you can use that directly. Once you have received new values either way you can just update your GUI in a Platform.runLater call.